How do I disable the dot that appears on a line series chart on hover? I am using 'lightweight-charts' with react
I am trying to disable this dot that appears on the line chart on hover.

I referred the lightweight chart docs and couldn't find anything related to this. This is my code for the chart initialisation.
this.chartContainerRef = chartContainerRef;
    this.chart = createChart(this.chartContainerRef.current, {
      layout: {
        background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: backgroundColor },
        textColor,
      },
      width: this.chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth,
      height: Math.max(this.chartContainerRef.current.clientHeight - 72, 0),
      handleScroll: false,
      handleScale: false,
      grid: {
        vertLines: {
          visible: false,
        },
        horzLines: {
          visible: false,
        },
      },
      crosshair: {
        vertLine: {
          visible: false,
          labelVisible: false, // Add this line to disable the vertical crosshair label
        },
        horzLine: {
          visible: false,
          labelVisible: false, // Add this line to disable the horizontal crosshair label
        },
      },
    });
    this.chart.timeScale().fitContent();
    this.chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
      rightOffset: 100,
      secondsVisible: true,
      timeVisible: true,
    });
    this.series = this.chart.addAreaSeries({
      lineColor,
      topColor: areaTopColor,
      bottomColor: areaBottomColor,
      lastPriceAnimation: 2,
      priceFormat: {
        // TODO: Infer precision from dataset
        precision: 6,
        minMove: 0.000001,
      },
    });

